# Pause execution on the main thread of iOS app while animation runs

Tags: ios, multithreading, animation

I am using a navigation controller, and I'm trying to run an animation before the new View Controller pushes.  To do this, I'm catching the event from the UINavigationController delegate, and running an animation.  That said, obviously iOS animations are meant to run asynchronously, so the method returns, and my animation runs concurrently with the standard push animation.  Any thoughts on how to get around this?

Situation looks like this:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (animated)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:kGFDefaultAnimationDuration
                                      delay:0.0
                                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                                 animations:^{
                                     // Set up animations here...
                                 }
                                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                                 }];
    }
}
```

So in other words, I'd like to return `navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated` from within the completion block.

Comment: How about doing the animation before pushing the new view controller? Once the animation is done, in completion block you can do the push.

Comment: @ACB how would I fire the initial event to start the animation?  I've tried overloading the `pushViewController:animated:` method, which works fine.  The issue is that I want a parallel effect with `popViewControllerAnimated:`, and that one is significantly more difficult to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Count you describe what the 'event' is? If its a method then you could just call it as [self method()]; where you have written '// Set up animations here...' first and then push your view controller in the completion block. Alternately you could simply write up your UIView animation code and use the `setAnimationDidStopSelector` and just set your method to push view controller as the selector. Ensure that you also set your view as the delegate via `[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];` That way the push view only happens after the animation completes. You can also look into `-(void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay` if you know the animation duration time and set the delay to perform a push view controller a fraction of a second before animation completes. Tweak it for the best result.